# Are Award Travel Changeable or Refundable?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs

For tickets purchased normally, there are tons of types of tickets with various rules regarding changes, cancellations and refunds, but what about for award travel. On the AAdvantage site, there seems to be just Economy or Business/First awards, with peak and off-peak versions for each.

**What change and refund rules generally apply to award tickets?**

Comment: Each airline applies different rules to award tickets, so there can be no "generally" answer.  You need to visit the website for each specific airline to determine the rules.  It is no less complicated than paid tickets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [AA's site](https://www.aa.com/i18n/aadvantage-program/miles/redeem/award-travel/award-travel.jsp#reinstating):

Changing flight awards
Contact American Airlines Reservations for assistance with changing a flight award ticket.

**Changes to the origin or destination or airline**

- > For MileSAAver awards, origin or destination changes to the itinerary
  >   will incur a change fee of $150, even when retaining the same award
  >   type
- > For awards involving travel on other airlines, origin or
  >   destination changes or changes to the airline(s) in the itinerary will
  >   incur a change fee of $150, even when retaining the same award type
- > For AAnytime awards, origin or destination change fees are waived only
  >   when retaining the same award type
- > The change fee will be waived for
  >   Executive Platinum members using miles from their account

**Reinstating flight awards**

- > You can request to have your AAdvantage mileage reinstated for a wholly
  >   unused AAdvantage award ticket and if the ticket has not expired
- > The
  >   reinstatement charge is $150 per account for the first award ticket.
  >   Additional award tickets reinstated to the same account at the same
  >   time will have a $25 charge per ticket
- > This fee will be waived for
  >   Executive Platinum members using miles from their account